# How to get the reason @dns_get_record function returns false

Tags: php, dns

I am trying to get dns txt record for

```
$dns_txt = @dns_get_record('airhelp.com', DNS_TXT);
```

but function return false.
is it possible somehow to debug this function or understand the reason why it fails?

Comment: Turn on error_reporting? Don't use @ to suppress errors?

Comment: thanks @kerbholz I did as you sad. I dot an error ```PHP Warning:  dns_get_record(): DNS Query failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\Main.class.php on line
 585
PHP Stack trace:``` but it is not informative

Comment: Works like a charm for me, but I'm on Linux - so it might be a Windows problem, sorry.